# Github как залить несколько сайтов

Tags: github, site

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть репозиторий senekisi.github.io, когда-то я его создавал для сайта, залил туда сайт, но щас немного испортил index файл.

Вопрос встал в другом. Как мне на мой репозиторий заливать несколько сайтов? У меня сейчас сделано 5 сайтов, написанных естественно на html5. Изучал с ломаным английским сам гитхаб и как они делают gh-pages, но нифига не понятно. Всё делал по инструкции, но не понимаю о каких проектах там идёт речь. Есть ли грамотное описание, пошаговая инструкция так сказать, как создать на одном репозитории несколько работающих сайтов?
P.S. я могу очистить(удалить) свой репозиторий, чтобы начать всё заново.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Использовать папки-поддиректории:

- nickname.github.io - корневая директория сайта (главная страница)
- nickname.github.io/site 1/ - поддиректория 1 (папка сайта 1)
- nickname.github.io/site 2/ - поддиректория 2 (папка сайта 2)
- nickname.github.io/site 3/ - поддиректория 3 (папка сайта 3)

**Вариант 2**

Сделать отдельный репозиторий для каждого сайта (это иногда удобнее, чем поддиректории) и в каждом таком репозитории создать ветку gh-pages. Соответственно содержимое будет автоматически расположено по адресу nickname.github.io/repo_name/

но в любом случае домен каждого сайта будет `nickname.github.io/site/`

В каждой папке которая будет корнем отдельного сайта должен быть свой index.html. Структура папок должна выглядеть так:

```
├── index.html
├── site1                                                              
│     └── index.html
└── site2
     └── index.html
```

Comment: папки папками, но вопрос такой, чтобы перемещаться по этим папкам мне надо сделать получается отдельный index.php который я положу в корень, где возможно будет по ссылкам переключаться в эти дополнительные сайты? я просто не могу допереть как gh-pages поменять права )

Comment: @Gwai дополнил свой ответ (написал структуру папок), поскольку в коментарии не можно вставить код.     index.php юзать не получится поскольку github-pages работает только с HTML файлами. Что Вы имеете ввиду поменять права?

Comment: Я в целом понял, что Вы имели ввиду. Не знаю просто как это реализовать, кодом :). Подумаю на досуге. Мне надо с ГИТом работать, а я не умею :)